# Filtering a ListView with a custom Array Adapter (Android)

Tags: android, listview

I've implemented a filter on my ListView, which is built on a custom array adapter. The list displays a celebrity name and a picture of that celebrity.

```
public class Celebrities extends ListActivity {

private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<CelebrityEntry> adapter = null;
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_celebrity);

     //disables the up button
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

     filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
     filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

     adapter = new CelebrityEntryAdapter(this, getModel());
     setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

And I've overridden the `toString()` method in CelebrityEntry.java:

```
public final class CelebrityEntry {

private String name;
private int pic;

public CelebrityEntry(String name, int pic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.pic = pic;
}

/**
 * @return name of celebrity
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
/**
 * override the toString function so filter will work
 */
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
/**
 * @return picture of celebrity
 */
public int getPic() {
    return pic;
}
```

}

However, when I boot up the app and start filtering, each list entry has the proper picture, but the names are just the original list, truncated to how many celebrities actually fulfilled the filter. Say Kirsten Dunst is the first entry in the list and Adam Savage is the second. If I filter for Adam Savage, I get his picture, but the name still says Kirsten Dunst, even though these two pieces of information are elements of a single object.

Obviously, this is not the desired result. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you include your adapter?

Comment: The adapter ended up being the problem. Figured it out this evening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you are using your adapter, so I will just show you what I do to filter a ListView with lazy loading (which will recycle the row views instead of inflating new views as you scroll).  Create a SlowAdapter inner class:

```
private class SlowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public SlowAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    public int getCount() {
        if (filtered) {
            return filteredItems.length;
        } else {
            return unfilteredItems.length;
        }
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout rowView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            rowView = (LinearLayout)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        } else {
            rowView = (LinearLayout)convertView;
        }
        ImageView celebrity_image = rowView.findViewById(R.id.celebrity_image);
        TextView celebrity_name = rowView.findViewById(R.id.celebrity_name);

        if (!filtered) { // use position to get the filtered item.
            CelebrityEntry c = filteredItems[position];
             // do what you do to set the image and text for a celebrity.

        } else { // use position to get the unfiltered item.
            CelebrityEntry c = unfilteredItems[position];
             // do what you do to set the image and text for a celebrity.                 
        }   
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Now in  your textWatcher, filter the celebrities based on the string into the array filteredItems, then just set filtered=true and create a new SlowAdapter and set that to your ListView.

unfilteredItems will be used when nothing is filtered, and it will be used for future filtering from a full source.